# Is there a way for me to use the 1st cell of a row as a getsheetbyname parameter in google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function onEdit(event) {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  
  if(s.getName() == "Sheet1" && r.getColumn() == 3 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("id1");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
    // s.deleteRow(row);
  } 
}
```

This is the code so far and I was wondering if there was a way for me to automatically append all of the row or "id" to their specific tab if their checkbox have been checked using the 1st cell of the row as the parameter for the getsheetbyname?

I tried to create a variable and put it in the getSheetByName() like the example below but it didn't work. I'm very new to javascript/apps script.

```
function onEdit(event) {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  
  if(s.getName() == "Sheet253" && r.getColumn() == 2 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var a = row[0];
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(a);
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
    // s.deleteRow(row);
  } 
}
```

This is an example of the google sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19TzSKyY4616sWpY2ONPj01F5CJDfsTJ7DmbFXPVKvJE/edit?usp=sharing

The result should look like the result in tab id1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, I thought that the event object can be used.
- In your sample Spreadsheet, it seems that the checkbox is put to the column "C". When you want to run the script, when the checkbox is checked, the checked column is the column "C".

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

From your provided sample Spreadsheet, this script supposes that the source sheet name is "Sheet1". Please be careful about this.

```js
function onEdit(event) {
  var ss = event.source;
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.range;
  if (s.getName() == "Sheet1" && r.columnStart == 3 && r.isChecked()) {
    var sheetName = r.offset(0, -2).getValue();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    if (!targetSheet) {
      Browser.msgBox(`"${sheetName}" was not found.`);
      return;
    }
    var row = r.rowStart;
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
    // s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

- In this script, when the checkbox of the column "C" of "Sheet1" is checked, the row is copied.

#### Note:

- In your showing script, the edited row is used. So I modified your script by following your showing script. But, about `This is the code so far and I was wondering if there was a way for me to automatically append all of the row or "id" to their specific tab if their checkbox has been checked using the 1st cell of the row as the parameter for the getsheetbyname?`, if you want to copy all rows by one execution of the script, how about the following sample script? When this script is run, the checkboxes of column "C" of "Sheet1" are checked, and each value are copied to each sheet using the values of column "A".

  ```js
  function sample() {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    const obj = srcSheet.getRange("A2:C" + srcSheet.getLastRow()).getValues().reduce((o, r) => {
      if (r[2] === true) {
        o[r[0]] = o[r[0]] ? [...o[r[0]], r] : [r];
      }
      return o;
    }, {});
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([name, values]) => {
      const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);
      const range = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length);
      range.setValues(values).offset(0, 2, values.length, 1).insertCheckboxes();
    });
  }
  ```

#### Note:

- This sample script is for your provided sample Spreadsheet. So, when you change the structure of the Spreadsheet, the script might not be able to be used. So, please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)